# How to add shadow to only top side of UIView without using shadow path and adding layers

Tags: ios, swift

How to add shadow to only topside of UIView without affecting other sides?. My view is based on constraints so using shadow path or inserting layer not worked properly.

```
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -2)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
```

[image]

Comment: There's a `shadowPath` property on `CALayer`.

Answer (score 0):

change view.layer.shadowRadius to 0 if you want the shadow to be only on the top

UPDATE:- to have shadow effect on top, add the shadowView (view on which shadow is needed) inside another view(containerView) and leave some spacing from the top (shadowView width is equal to containerView width), make sure that the containerView.clipsToBounds = true. Apply all your code to shadowView, you should see a shadow on the top.

Comment: It is removing shadow effect from top side also.